# Storing 3D Spatial Data With EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I'm creating a web shop using .NET Core and I'm storing all of the product information in a SQL database using EF Core.

As a part of this, I would like to store the x, y, and z dimension of each product. But I'm wondering about the best way of storing three values that belong together in this way in a database using EF Core.

EF Core doesn't allow me to store them as an array or list of for example floats or integers, and I want to avoid creating a dedicated model concered only with the three dimensional size values for each product.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Store it as a Json column ([Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829824/how-to-store-json-in-an-entity-field-with-ef-core)) and if you frequently run read queries on it then setup indexes.