# What configurations do I have to add to my DbContext to store property of type IDictionary<string, object>

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a domain entity in my code where i have property `Parameters` which is of type `Dictionary<string, object>`. I have tried to add `JsonConvert`. But the data gets changed while storing in db.

Task.cs

```
public sealed class Task
{
    
    public Guid TaskId { get; set; }
    public Guid QueryId { get; set; }
    public Guid DatabaseId { get; set; }
    public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public string Status { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public IDictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

DbContext.cs

```
public interface IDbContext
{
    DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; }
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess = true, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}

internal sealed class QueryHubDbContext : DbContext, IQueryHubDbContext
{
    public QueryHubDbContext(DbContextOptions<QueryHubDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks => Set<Task>();
   

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Query>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
            entity.Property(e => e.Tags)
            .HasConversion(
                v => string.Join(',', v.Where(tag => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tag))),
                v => v.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Task>(ConfigureTask);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    private void ConfigureTask(EntityTypeBuilder<Task> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(e => e.TaskId);
        builder.Property(e => e.TaskId).ValueGeneratedNever();
         builder.Property(e => e.Parameters)
            .HasConversion(
                v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
                v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(v) ?? new Dictionary<string, object>())
            .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");
    }
}
```

with these configuration i when i pass

```
{
  "taskId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "queryId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "databaseId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "organizationId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "status": "string",
  "parameters": {
    "additionalProp1": "string",
    "additionalProp2": "string",
    "additionalProp3": "string"
  }
}
```

Data stored in the db ->

```
{
  "taskId": "9abf0000-76ab-40b0-d1d5-08dbf0421eaa",
  "queryId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "databaseId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "organizationId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "status": "",
  "parameters": {
    "additionalProp1": {
      "valueKind": []
    },
    "additionalProp2": {
      "valueKind": []
    },
    "additionalProp3": {
      "valueKind": []
    }
  }
}
```

I am using SqlServer as my Db. There exist a db type "json" or "jsonb" for postgres. There  doesnt for sql server.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829824/how-to-store-json-in-an-entity-field-with-ef-core.  What you may be missing is #null handling (`new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }`) Though you may want to take mapping the JSON string to backing field approach and using the JsonConvert in a `[NotMapped]` property accessor since you won't be able to reference the `Dictionary<stirng,object>` in your queries in any case.

Comment: Actually it works with `[NotMapped]` and using a backing field. But i don't want to add Database related configurations in my domain model. I tried adding the JsonSerializerSettings you recommanded. Still it gives me the same thing.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want the `[NotMapped]` attribute in your entity definition? If so, you can configure it instead with fluent configuration: `builder.Ignore(e => e.Parameters)`

Comment: But i will still have to add `public string SerializedParameters` in my domain entity?

Comment: No, just a private backing field. You can hide it in a region or a partial file if you really don't want to see it. Entity class definitions are your data domain and should contain data domain related state which may include some specific implementations. Relying on saving lists within fields honestly should be an exception not a norm in a design as it doesn't facilitate things like indexing & such within relational data models. If these lists have any value for filtering etc. they they should be broken out into tables where the relationship can be formalized and indexed.

Comment: Can you show me a small piece of code. It would be of great help?

Comment: ```
public IDictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    
    public string SerializedParameters
    {
        get => JsonSerializer.Serialize(Parameters); 
        set => Parameters = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IDictionary<string, object>>(value) ?? new Dictionary<string, object>(); 
    }

```

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ExecuteQueryTask>()
            .Ignore(e => e.Parameters)
            .Property(e => e.SerializedParameters)
            .HasColumnName("Parameters");
```

This approach works.

Comment: Now I have to figure out a way to move the serialization code to Dbcontext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested pass the data with some difference having no problem.
Task.cs

```
    public class Task
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
```

MyContext.cs

```
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql("server=192.168.2.68;database=wa76;user=mysql1;password=xxxxx", new MySqlServerVersion(new Version()));
        }

        public DbSet<Task> TaskTable { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
                .Property(b => b.Parameters)
                .HasConversion(
                    v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
                    v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(v));
        }
    }
```

controller

```
        [HttpPost("test")]
        public void test(object obj)
        {
            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Task>(obj.ToString());
            _context.Add(model);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Test 
Postman:
[image]
Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to test. Can you try sending the data from Swagger or Postman?

Comment: @HardikDhuri I edit to a postman test, you could have a try.

Comment: Thanks it solves the problem. Thank you for your efforts