# JSON polymorphic type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a class like this:

```
public class Device
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public long StationId { get; set; }
    public Station Station { get; set; }

    public DeviceTypeEnum Type { get; set; }
    public FacilityStatusEnum Status { get; set; }
    public MonitorDeviceExtraInfo ExtraInfo { get; set; };
}
```

The type of `ExtraInfo` in the class is `MonitorDeviceExtraInfo`, which has many subclasses and corresponds to the type of device. I hope it is stored in the database as a JSON type in `ExtraInfo` and the type of this JSON is determined based on the Type.

May I know how to implement this feature?

I tried the dependent attribute, but it does not support polymorphism and inheritance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store JSON in an entity field with EF Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829824/how-to-store-json-in-an-entity-field-with-ef-core)